# Share from FBSDK 3.22 (iOS/Android) without asking for publish_action permission

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

I have an old app that was passed to me from another developer.
The app uses Facebook SDK 3.22 and uses it very intensively (dozens of calls all over the app, without any central manager).
I was asked to 'fix' it, as it has stopped working few months ago (since FB has started requiring to submit the app to their review for using `publish_action` permission).

I have 2 obvious solutions:

- Upgrade to latest FB SDK and use one of the new sharing options
- Send the app to review and wait for it to be approved during 5-7 days

My question here is whether there is a way to publish (something like `[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:parameters:handler:]`) without asking `publish_action` permission.

Maybe use some another dialog?

Thank you.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Comment: @CBroe, haven't you read my question?..

Answer (score 2):

with out `publish_actions` you can't use, if you this `publish_actions`, you need to submit your app to facebook review before submission of appreview from apple.

you can use the alternate way of FB Share use [**UIActivityViewController**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/)

for example

```
 NSString *textToShare = @"Look at this awesome website for aspiring iOS Developers!";
NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.XXXX.com/"];

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

for example see [this](http://www.codingexplorer.com/add-sharing-to-your-app-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/)